# clone column1 to column 2 using button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need another name2 column where in it has a button(copy all) once you click it a dialog box will appear "Are you sure you want to copy |Yes/No". it'll clone the data from name to name2.

```
<table class="downpanel">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name2</th>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="">Count</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Data2</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="copyall">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="25" name="name">
            </td>
             <td>
                <input type="text" size="25" name="name2">
            </td>   
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="copy">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="3" name="from">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="3" name="to">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="copy">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="unit" style="width: 75px;">
                    <option value="blah">blah</option>
                </select>
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="copy">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="category" style="width: 275px;">
                    <option value="blah">blah</option>
                </select>
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="copy">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="10" id="datepicker" name="data1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="copy">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="7" name="data2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="copy">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/hq2GG/2/

Comment: You mean add new row with all the fields one by one

Comment: no i mean in "name2" column there is a button that once you click it. it'll clone/copy all the data in column "name". i have done it but it copy per row. now i need a button per column that will copy the previous data in a column ex: if the date today is june 16(col1) in june 17(col2) has a button to copy the data in col1. if you have another june 18(col3) it'll copy the the data in col2 like that. i hope you get my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/hq2GG/4/

```
 var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to copy?");
```

in both copy and copy all

http://jsfiddle.net/hq2GG/6/

Comment: thank you for this. its perfect. last, if i put button per column same function as the button per row that copy preview data is that posible

Comment: yes you can add this code in your .on('click', '.copy', function () method as in copyall method

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a mode mash up issue. You initiated your data using HTML and now you want to manipulate it via Javascript. The more complex your issues get, the more you will end up in coding chaos. This is NOT about mixing different coding practices but to break the conceptual rework by designing one part in HTML and the other in Javascript. So as javascript seems to be mandatory here first design everything as if your whole application would only consist of Javascript. Define a mode:

1. DOM-Node-Manipulation (would be state of the art and also easier for manipulation) OR
2. html compile style (using innerHTML)

Once you got a mode make your matrix a matrix. If you need to copy cells, respectively rows and columns, you need to be able to address those. In the DOM Model you could maintain a two-dimensional wrapper array, in the html compile style you would obviously fittle with IDs, such as cell1_3, which helps you to make use of the getElementById. At the point in time you are able to address elements, it is just a matter of formulating loops, to get things copied, moved or deleted in bulk mode.

Once you got all of the conceptional prework you can decide to prefill your html page with html (and not javascript) - however this must follow the rules you set yourself for the scripting mode.